Angular p-dropdown disabled property not working with reactive formcontrol
<p-dropdown formControlName="signatures" [disabled]="true" placeholder="Please Select Signature" [options]="signatureOptions" (onChange)="selectSignature($event,rowIndex)"></p-dropdown>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

I was using the Angular 11 version, and the 'disabled' property was working fine with p-dropdown when using formControl. However, after upgrading to Angular 17, the disabled property stopped working due to formControl. When I remove formControlName, the disabled property starts working fine.

Since Angualr17 you should use the methods disable and enable of the FormControl.

You should use something like this to disable it:
this.form.get('signatures')?.disable();

and something like this to enable it:
this.form.get('signatures')?.enable();

This is because you should use enable and disable since Angular version 17 or higher as Eliseo has already pointed out in his comment.

To use 'disabled' with 'formControl,' you have to set the 'disabled' property while initializing 'formControl' like this, then it will work fine."
signatures  = new FormControl({value : '', disabled: true});
